# How to get Ubuntu-desktop back after once removing it completely

Tags: lubuntu, kubuntu, 19.04, desktop-environments, 19.10

In past 6 months, I have tried to experiment with different desktop environments. At first, I completely removed Ubuntu-desktop-environment and installed Kubuntu-desktop. It was successful. Then after some days I installed Lubuntu-dektop. It was successful too. However, I miss Ubuntu-desktop now, and I want to get back to my Ubuntu-desktop. How to do it?

Thanks.

**Update**:
I have done the following:

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

And as a result I have got many options to login with. But When I choose Ubuntu after reconfiguring into `lightdm` it says insufficient memory.

I also tried reconfiguring to `gdm` and after reboot it does not show previous users but shows a welcome screen to create a new user. After I make a new user, I login just to get a black screen.

Now, as suggested by [WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix), I tried

`sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm`

and `lightdm` error is gone. I am able to log into `unity-dektop`, now.

`gdm` part is still remaining.

Comment: First, for the purposes of experimentation, I would suggest playing with a VM until you find what you like. Then you don't have these problems. Secondly, what is your memory and disk space like before you log in? You could use CTRL-ALT-F1 to open a virtual terminal and get the answers with `df` and `free` and then get back with CTRL-ALT-F7.

Comment: Can't test on my phone but suggest `sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm`

Comment: This is a problem that is known to be difficult, and you may have to re-install to get a fully working system. I agree with @wxl, that you should do such experiments with a separate test system in a virtual machine or a separate computer, not with your main working system.

Comment: Which Ubuntu desktop are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu19.10 Beta

Comment: do a Clonezilla backup of the whole partition or disk before doing anything radical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
sudo apt install tasksel

sudo tasksel
```

choose your required desktop environment.
[See the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVJXq.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to install ubuntu-desktop and leave lubuntu installed, it is much easier to reinstall Ubuntu

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop lightdm`

We included lightdm in case it was removed

You may also need to reconfigure lightdm

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

If you wish to remove lubuntu-desktop you will need to examine the package and remove them one by one, you do not want to remove or purge the desktop, depending on your situation this may produce unpredictable results
While the notes say that it's ok to use `apt remove lubuntu-desktop` I have destroyed several installations this way

Since ubuntu-desktop and lubuntu-desktop are meta-packages you may have some luck examining the differences between the two with commands like `apt show ubuntu-desktop` and `apt show lubuntu-desktop`

If you are having problems with other packages that are installed you could try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure package-name` on the package you are having trouble with, this will resolve most issues

Comment: I've already tried installing `ubuntu-desktop lightdm` and `gdm` as well.

Comment: you do not want gdm, where do you appear to be getting stuck?

Answer (score -1):

Make a backup from your important data. Before you install anew try

```
sudo apt purge lubuntu-desktop lubuntu-default-session  kubuntu-desktop plasma-desktop  plasma-workspace
```

Make a simulation for

```
sudo apt --dry-run autoremove purge
```

Take a good look, what would be removed. You need a displaymanager and a networkmanager on your system.

```
sudo apt autoremove purge
```

Comment: I can see your got intentions, but honestly those commands look rather destructive, a purge for packages included by meta packages are known to include packages required by the system and removal of them is not always desirable

Comment: @Steve you're not wrong, but i) this is offered only as a last ditch attempt before reinstalling ("*Before you install anew try...*) ii) it suggests running a dry run first and "*taking a good look*" at what will be removed. Since this is just something to try if you're about to reinstall anyway, I don't see any problem and it might even help.